# Tokenising a String containing empty tokens

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer, split

I have a seemingly simple problem of splitting a comma separated `String` into tokens, whereby the output should include empty tokens in cases where:

- The first character in the `String` is a comma.
- The last character in the `String` is a comma.
- Two consecutive commas occur.

For example, for the `String`: `",abd,def,,ghi,"` should yield the output: `{"", "abd", "def", "", "ghi", ""}`.

I have tried using `String.split`, `Scanner` and `StringTokenizer` for this but each gives a different undesired output (examples below).  Can anyone suggest an **elegant** solution for this, preferably using JDK classes?  Obviously I could code something myself but I feel like I'm missing something on one of the three approaches mentioned.  Note that the delimiter is a fixed `String` although not necessarily a comma, nor a single character.

**Example Code**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main12 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = ",abd,def,,ghi,";
    String[] tokens = s.split(",");

    System.err.println("--- String.split Output ---");
    System.err.println(String.format("%s -> %s", s, Arrays.asList(tokens)));

    for (int i=0; i<tokens.length; ++i) {
      System.err.println(String.format("tokens[%d] = %s", i, tokens[i]));
    }

    System.err.println("--- Scanner Output ---");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    sc.useDelimiter(",");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
      System.err.println(sc.next());
    }

    System.err.println("--- StringTokenizer Output ---");

    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
    while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
      System.err.println(tok.nextToken());
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
$ java Main12
--- String.split Output ---
,abd,def,,ghi, -> [, abd, def, , ghi]
tokens[0] =
tokens[1] = abd
tokens[2] = def
tokens[3] =
tokens[4] = ghi
--- Scanner Output ---
abd
def

ghi
--- StringTokenizer Output ---
abd
def
ghi
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Pass a `-1` to `split` as the `limit` argument:

```
String s = ",abd,def,,ghi,";
String[] tokens = s.split(",", -1);
```

Then your result array will include any trailing empty strings.

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> If [the limit] is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.  If [the limit] is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Calling `split(regex)` acts as if the `limit` argument is `0`, so trailing empty strings are discarded.